# How to reference properties in jcr

Tags: reference, nodes, jcr

Suppose I have a node in a JCR that provides properties for a movie, such as title, director and actors, in english. I then have another node that stores the same properties, but in another language, say French. Is there a way to have the french node reference the english one, such that only properties that need to be translated are actually stored on the second node. ex:

-englishNode
Properties
Title: The Sword in the Stone
Director: Wolfgang Reitherman
Actor: Sebastian Cabot

-frenchNode
Properties
Title: Merlin L'Enchanteur

But then director and actor properties would be retrieved from the english node as they don't need to be translated. Calling frenchNode.getProperty("director") though, would need to retrieve the property from the englishNode.

I know that I can make the french node a child of the english one and have its properties inherited down, but I need a structure where all english movies live under an english node and all French movies live under a French node, so a french movie cannot be a sibling of an english one but will rather be a "cousin".

Answer (score 1):

I know of nothing in JCR that directly accommodates this scenario. But I can think of several possible options. Each has its own benefits, and one solution might work well in one situation while being abysmal in others.

**Local-specific child nodes**
Make one language the primary language (e.g., whatever the fallback or more popular local might be), and place local-specific properties on local-specific children under that node. So if English were the primary language, then the movie properties might be stored on the movie node. French properties might be stored on a "fr" child, German on a "de" child, etc. One advantage is that your application needs only load the locales it uses.

**Fallback References**
Create a reference property from one node to the "fallback", and have your logic take this into account when retrieving a property. If the property is not on the node, get it from the fallback, where the fallback node can be retrieved with `movie.getProperty("fallback").getNode()`. (Note that it's very easy to make this recursive, where the fallback might have a fallback.) This allows the nodes to be stored in separate locations. Be wary about circular fallback references, though (where the fallback for the English is the French, and the fallback for the French is the English); this is possible to handle, but it requires tracking some state. Again, your application only loads the nodes with locale-specific properties as needed.

**Local-specific Properties**
Store on the movie node all properties, including the title in English, French and any other languages. Use a suffix or prefix on the property name to denote the locale (e.g., `en-title` and `fr-title`). Loading a single node tends to load all of the locale-variations for all properties. Therefore, this works well with fewer languages, fewer local-specific properties, and fewer overall properties.

**Child node for each "property"**
Place each "property" (such as 'title') as a child node, with each locale-specific value stored as a property. Again, since loading nodes would load the values for all locales, this would work better with a smaller number of languages and locale-specific values.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't think JCR provides something out of the box.

In [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/), we use a similar mechanism to allow "system" scripts to be overridden by "user" scripts: to process a given request Sling might find that a script at /libs/foo/foo.esp is a good candidate, but if there's another script at /apps/foo/foo.esp it will be used instead.

You could do the same by overriding say the /content/books/en/title property with /content/books/fr/title if the latter exists. You'll have to do that at the application level, but such a "parallel paths" structure is clean and simple to understand and manage, you just need to define which part of the path represents the content's locale.